# Windows 8.1 Dual GPU freezing

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, freeze, windows-8.1, gpu

I'm almost killing myself here trying to make this computer work with two GPUs.
It works fine using one GPU; all drivers are up to date. 
After inserting the second GPU, about two minutes after Windows login,
it completely freezes.

I have no idea why is that happening.

This is my configuration:

- Intel Pentium G3220
- Kingston 4gb 1600Mhz Hyper-X Blu
- 2x Sapphire R9-280x 3GGDR5 OC-BF 4 Edition
- TS-1250PSZ Seventeam 1250w PSU
- Seagate HD 500GB 7200 RPM

I have just one monitor, tried many things without success.
Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by freeze?  Blue screen?  Video stays up but system just stops responding to all input?  System shutsdown completely?  Something else?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using? (You have tagged both [windows-7] and [windows-8.1].)

Comment: Have you tried both graphics cards alone to verify that one isn't the problem? The second one you insert could be a bad card. If it happens in either configuration, that gives us more detail at least. Also, how many RAM modules are there? Motherboard info would be helpful, too.

Comment: How many watts is your PSU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting here I did exactly the same Joshua said, then I got a third card and I figure out the second one was somehow problematic, then I shipped it back to the store =)

I tagged 2 OS's because I tried on both versions on windows.
My PSU has 1250w.

Thanks for the replies

Comment: That PSU is overkill, you're wasting a ton of electricity.

Comment: Not really, you don't know my purpose using this PSU, also, you don't know how many GPU's I gonna put on this computer. ;) Hope the you're the one which put -1 to me, that certainly would explain why I got that.

Comment: Nope, I didn't downvote. Don't know why they did, "bad card" is a perfectly valid answer. Here's an upvote for ya!